# Remove default validation of DateTimeOffset

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I am struggling to remove default validation text of DateTimeOffset field.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="BirthDate">Birth Date</label>
            <span  style="font-style:italic; font-size:12px;"> Year-month-Day || 2019-12-23</span>
            <br><span asp-validation-for="BirthDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            <input type ="text" asp-for="BirthDate" class="form-control" novalidate/>
        </div>
```

Controller from where validation error text should be passed :

```
                if (model.BirthDate == null) {
                    ModelState.AddModelError ("BirthDate", "birthdate can not be null");
                    validator = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    if (!model.BirthDate.ToString().Contains ('-')) {
                        ModelState.AddModelError ("BirthDate", "incorrect format");
                        validator = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

ApplicationUser.cs

```
        public DateTimeOffset BirthDate { get; set; }
```

RegisterViewModel - Viewmodel I am using in Register View

```
        public DateTimeOffset BirthDate { get; set; }
```

Error text I am getting is for example this :

> The value '' is invalid.
>   Which I have not written anywhere.

I tried to give custom validation text in Required attribute but it still gets overridden. 
I also tried disabling default validation in Startup.cs like this:

```
        services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
        });
```

Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For custom `DateTimeOffset` error, you could try to change `DateTimeOffset` to `string` in `RegisterViewModel` like

```
    public string  BirthDate { get; set; }
```

And then validate the `BirthDate` with your code. After it is validate, you could convert this string to `ApplicationUser.DateTimeOffset`.